# How to display paginated posts from all categories?

Tags: pagination

I found this code that helps to paginate the posts of one specific category, how can I change it to have a posts paginate function for all categories? (WordPress)

```php
global $wp_query;
$result = new WP_Query('cat=3');//replace with your desired category id
$args_pagi = array(
            'base' => add_query_arg( 'paged', '%#%' ),
            'total' => $result->max_num_pages,
            'current' => $page
        );

$args =array('post_type' => 'post','post_status' => 'publish','cat' => 3);
$myposts = new WP_Query( $args );


foreach( $myposts->posts as $data ) : setup_postdata($data);
    // your desired code
endforeach;

//call pagination function
echo paginate_links( $args_pagi);
```

Answer (score 0):

A basic `WP_Query` instance and loop will work (untested):

```php
$posts = new WP_Query( array(
    'paged' => get_query_var( 'paged', 1 ),
) );

while ( $posts->have_posts() ) {
    $posts->the_post();

    ...
}

$current_page = 1;

if ( isset( $_GET['paged'] ) ) {
    $current_page = absint( $_GET['paged'] );
}

echo paginate_links( array(
    'base'    => add_query_arg( 'paged', '%#%' ),
    'total'   => $posts->max_num_pages,
    'current' => $current_page,
) );
```